# Can I declare GPS service to run an iOS background service?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app needs to run forever in background to do something like: upload/download, encrypt/decrypt files, etc. This app likes a web service to listen requests from another apps in same device. I am not afford to use external web service.
I know iOS do not allow to run when go into background mode. I am going to declare my app using GPS to use some others specific functions. Does it conflict Apple policy? Can I upload to App Store later?

Comment: Abusing background modes definitely conflicts with Apple guidelines and will get your app rejected. Also it won't help you with what you are trying to do anyway. iOS will wake your app periodically to deliver location updates but this won't allow your app to listen on a socket and serve clients

Comment: to keep running your app in a background you can use GPS function but it will not keep your app running always in a background mode. in that case what you can do is try to get the location after every 2-3 min. in that way your app will be always running. but it will cause a battery problem as your app will run forever in a background.

Comment: checkout this link http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7